# Lower bound on sum of two least square problems

Tags: matrices, optimization, least-squares

Let $D, E \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ be full rank matrices where $m \geq n$.

---

**Question:**

Is
$
\Big(
\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}} \|Dx-b\|^2+\|Ex-y\|^2\
\Big)
>0
$

---

**My try:**

If we let the gradient of the objective function be zero we get the following:
$$
D^{\top}Dx*+E^{\top}Ex*=D^{\top}b+E^{\top}y
$$

Matrices $D$ and $E$ are full rank so $D^{\top}D$ and $E^{\top}E$ are positive definite matrices. Thus, $C= D^{\top}D+E^{\top}E$ is a positive definite matrix. As a result $x*$ is unique and can be found as follows:
$$
x*=c^{-1}(D^{\top}b+E^{\top}y)
$$

---

**Question:**

How can I rule out $x*$ does not make the objective value zero? Or conditions that rule it out?

Comment: Shouldn't it depend whether $b \in \mathcal{R}(D)$ and $y \in \mathcal{R}(E)$ the fact that you can achieve a zero error?

Comment: @VanBaffo: can you elaborate on you question?

Answer (score 1):

First, if $\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \lVert Dx-b\rVert^2>0$ or $\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \lVert Ex-y\rVert^2>0$, then the objective value is clearly nonzero.
To check it, evaluate the functions at their minimum for each of these problems (minimum reached for $x'=(D^TD)^{-1}Db$ and $x''=(E^TE)^{-1}Ey$ respectively).

Now, assuming that $\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \lVert Dx-b\rVert^2=0$ and $\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \lVert Ex-y\rVert^2=0$, we would like to know when $\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \lVert Dx-b\rVert^2 + \lVert Ex-y\rVert^2=0.$

We have:
$$
\begin{align} 
&\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \lVert Dx-b\rVert^2 + \lVert Ex-y\rVert^2=0\\ 
\iff &\lVert Dx^*-b\rVert^2 + \lVert Ex^*-y\rVert^2=0 \\
\iff & \lVert Dx^*-b\rVert^2 = 0 \text{ and } \lVert Ex^*-y\rVert^2=0\\
\iff &x^*=x' \text{ and } x^*=x''\\
\iff & x'=x''
\end{align}
$$

So a necessary and sufficient condition for $\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \lVert Dx-b\rVert^2 + \lVert Ex-y\rVert^2$ to be zero is $\lVert Dx'-b\rVert^2=0$ and $\lVert Ex'-y\rVert^2=0$ for $x'= (D^TD)^{-1}Db.$